# Separate CSS files using create-react-app code-splitting without ejecting

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I am using `react-loadable` to leverage code-splitting due to my application becoming too large not to do this. This is all working but the CSS is embedded in these new JavaScript chunks and then seemingly dynamically loaded into the page. I would like the CSS from each of these chunks to be in separate files rather than inside the JS file itself. Can I accomplish this without ejecting and modifying th Webpack config myself? I would really like to avoid that if possible.

**EDIT:**
I've just ejected to see what the actual Webpack configuration is doing. The following comment confirms the issue I'm having but doesn't offer a solution:

[image]

Note the last sentence:

> If you use code splitting, however, any async bundles will still use the
>   "style" loader inside the async code so CSS from them won't be in the
>   main CSS file.

Comment: During development, the styles are injected to help with hot reloading. CSS files should be created when you run `npm build`. I'm not 100% in the case of `create-react-app` so give it a check and see what it does.

Comment: It doesn't. It gives me a main.[hash].css which is quite small and then most of the css is embedded in the JavaScript chunks and then loaded in dynamically with unhelpful unique id names like "www.domain.com/3b80c92c-62f0-46d1-b61c-449df357696d"

Comment: I'm getting a very different result when I eject with a new `create-react-app`, the use of `ExtractTextPlugin` indicates to me it might be a version thing because if you go to the plugin page it recommends using `MiniCssExtractPlugin` for anything CSS related. Which my version does.

I'm just doing a test now.

Comment: MiniCssExtractPlugin is for Webpack 4+. My project gives me version 3.8.something when I eject. My project is over a year old so for whatever reason, it doesn't eject to Webpack 4+.

Answer (score 3):

I **don't believe so**, the purpose of `create-react-app` is to give you *useful defaults for your project's build-configuration* as well as to provide a *base template for your application's project structure*. The main idea is that `create-react-app` will allow you to focus on building out your application as opposed to worrying about setting up various build configurations, such as `Webpack` for bundling assets, `babel` for transpiling JavaScript code, linting, etc... `create-react-app` is a great "cookie-cutter" solution for most web applications, but it won't solve an edge case, such as custom performance need due to growth in your application's scale. Another analogy would be, it's kind of similar to  working out or following a diet plan: you know basic compound movements, for a given set/rep range, along with eating healthy foods, within your macronutrients needs, will help you achieve your best physique possible.... but to get stage ready it's that minor 5-10% of individual customization that makes or breaks your chances at winning. This is why actors/actresses/athletes/etc.. all have dieticians, chefs, and strength coaches which personalize this basic template, for success, on a per individual level. Back to your issue, from the sounds of it you need to modify your `MiniCssExtractPlugin` plugin settings from within your `webpack.config.js` to chunk your `CSS` appropriately into individual files. Maybe you could try the following:

1. Backup your source code up on a version control system such as Github, Bitbucket, etc... As you will most certainly break things on this trial and error journey. Then branch off of master so as to not ruin your main branch with a working application.

Now you've two options that you could perhaps try:

1. All your build configuration settings are within your `webpack.config.js`, even when you use `create-react-app`. As this *configuration is just encapsulated within the `react-scripts` node module*. So maybe you could try editing this file directly, without ejecting: `<base_path>/node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js` Although you need to be careful as to not break an existing configuration setting. At least this way if you ruin this file you can always just remove and reinstall `react-scripts` and be back to your initial configuration. This will also allow you to play around with your customizations in 'semi-safe' sandboxed environment.
2. Pull up your big boy pants and eject! Although this isn't most certainly what you wanted to hear.. you've customization needs, due to scale, that most people never need to account for so this requires a custom configuration. Similar to the exercise/diet plan analogy I gave earlier. If there is any saving grace remember there is *no magic that `create-react-app` is providing* rather it's just making useful defaults for your build configuration. By ejecting you still can use the application as before but now you're on you're own moving forward, which if you weren't using `create-react-app` this would be the case anyways.

Hopefully that helps, best of luck to you! If you figure out an elegant solution then please share with others, I hope to be proven wrong :)

Comment: Thanks Nathan. I appreciate the effort you put in to writing this. Fortunately I've discovered that this project was created over a year ago and was using an old version of `react-scripts` which was using Webpack 3.8. This still uses `ExtractTextPlugin` which doesn't seem to work with code-splitting. I have upgraded my `react-scripts` version to the latest which I know is using Webpack 4+ and `MiniCssExtractPlugin` and I now have CSS chunks! :D

Answer (score 1):

I think at this point I can confirm that it's an issue the version of `create-react-app` that you used to create the project. It's not an issue with `react-loadable` it's the dynamic `import()` syntax and the lack of support for it in `ExtractTextPlugin` not finding chunks from that syntax.

I did a test on my machine with the new `create-react-app`. You can see that the bundle is created when loaded dynamically.

[image]

Here is a link to the issue on `extract-text-webpack-plugin`. This feature will not be added to this plugin (see last comments): https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin/issues/455

So what you need to do now is find a way to switch to `MiniCssExtractPlugin`, which I think is your only option at this point if you want to extract that CSS.

**Edit:** For future Google-ers. MiniCssExtractPlugin doesn't support Webpack 3, you need to upgrade to 4 entirely.

Comment: I think you're right Richard. I had just come to that conclusion myself. Apologies for my ignorance on this. I have just recently inherited this project from a third party and my React experience is minimal at best. My `react-scripts` version was `1.1.5`. I created a brand new dummy project using `create-react-app` to see what version it was using and it was `2.1.8`! Time for an upgrade I think! I've just upgraded that and also upgraded react and react-dom packages to those in my dummy project. Currently getting a `Typo in prop type chain qualifier: isRequire  react/no-typos` error on build...

Comment: We're in business! I've fixed the typo (isRequire -> isRequired) and it's now emitting chunks of css!

Comment: Yes, it's probably for the best you just upgrade everything, Webpack 4 was a big leap forward and the more I look into it the more I see it's a fundamental issue with Webpack 3. And don't worry about being ignorant, Webpack is a difficult beast to tame at the best of times!